# how to convert array using filter method from values of another array in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, filter

I've array like this

```
const data: { "status" : ["aa","bb","cc","dd"],
                       ["ee","ff","gg","hh"],
                       ["ii","jj","kk","ll"] } 
const value=2;
```

and another array like this

```
const array2: { "name":"status", "data": ["cc","gg"] }
```

I want to convert array1 into this

```
const data: "status" : ["aa","bb","cc","dd"],
                      ["ee","ff","gg","hh"]
```

here Value is the index where I get the data which I have to filter from second array.
and in array1, data has the key value pair where status is the key and value is the array

I use the filter method. but I'm not able to travel through status to filter the array.

P.S. thank you in advance

Comment: Please show what you have attempted.

Comment: Are array1 and array2 are actually arrays ?

Comment: Please don't just delete and re-post [the same question again](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63468559/how-to-filter-array-value-using-another-array-in-javascript). This is the *third* time you've posted it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not positive if this is what you are asking for, but it seems like you're wanting to trim the arrays of `data.status` to only the ones that contain at least one of the values in `array2.data`.

To check this, in your filter you can use the [`some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) array method and check if each element is included in `array2.data`.

```js
const data = {
  "status": [
    ["aa", "bb", "cc", "dd"],
    ["ee", "ff", "gg", "hh"],
    ["ii", "jj", "kk", "ll"]
  ]
}

const array2 = {
  "name": "status",
  "data": ["cc", "gg"]
}

console.log('Before')
console.log(data.status)

data.status = data.status.filter(row => row.some(elem => array2.data.includes(elem)))

console.log('After')
console.log(data.status)
```